# ExoPlayer.Builder(context) is deprecated but i did not find anything in its doc(Android studio)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, deprecated, exoplayer

What the `ExoPlayer` doc says about `ExoPlayer.Builder()`:

> You can create an `ExoPlayer` instance using `ExoPlayer.Builder`, which provides a range of customization options. The code below is the simplest example of creating an instance:
>
> ```
> ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
> ```

I wrote the same thing in Android Studio like below:

```
val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
```

However, Android Studio strikes-through `ExoPlayer` like below:

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTog6.png)

Where can I find a replacement?

Comment: It looks like perhaps you have an obsolete `import` for `ExoPlayer`. What is the `import` statement that you are using for `ExoPlayer`?

Comment: Exoplayer has been constantly pushing updates and deprecating things all over the place with no example codes anywhere, i'd suggest to just save yourself the trouble and delay it until strictly necessary or few months until documentation appears.

Comment: @CommonsWare 
this is my Implementaion : `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.19.0' 
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.19.0'
`

Comment: Sorry, but I asked about your `import` statement. In the file that is giving you the error, if you scroll towards the top, you should see a bunch of lines starting with `import`. What is the `import` statement that you are using for the `ExoPlayer` class?

Answer (score 0):

The `ExoPlayer` you are using (com.google.android.exoplayer2) is now deprecated. You should migrate to androidx.media3 which has the same exoplayer as version 2.19.0. Refer to [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media3/getting-started/migration-guide) for migration guide.